# solr standalone: create core using coreadmin api - configset not found

Tags: solr

I've just installed solr in standalone mode.

I'm trying to create a core using api v1:

```
$ curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=arxius&configSet=_default"
```

As you can see, I'm trying to create a core `"arxius"` using `"_default"` configset.

`_default" configset is located at:

```
$ ls /opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/
_default  sample_techproducts_configs
```

When I perform curl command, I'm getting an error message:

```
{
   "responseHeader":{
      "status":400,
      "QTime":2
   },
   "error":{
      "metadata":[
         "error-class",
         "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
         "root-error-class",
         "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"
      ],
      "msg":"Error CREATEing SolrCore 'arxius': Unable to create core [arxius] Caused by: Could not load configuration from directory /var/solr/data/configsets/_default",
      "code":400
   }
}
```

It's trying to look up at `/var/solr/data/configsets/_default` instead beneath on `/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/` where is located by default after installation process.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using the zookeeper? if yes .then upload the config set..zkcli.bat -zkhost localhost:2181 -cmd upconfig -confname _default -confdir C:/solr-7.6.0/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf

Comment: No, I've installed solr in standalone mode.

Comment: Have you perhaps changed your SOLR_HOME to /var/solr/data?

Comment: I've changed nothing. I've just installed solr using [this ansible role](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-solr).

Comment: That role specifies `solr_home: /var/solr`, which is why Solr is looking for its configuration there. I'm guessing the role author assumes that you already have, or create a set of configuration by yourself explicitly under `/var/solr`, instead of using the built-in default config set. copying the directory there (.. but in that case, you probably want to use a custom name) should work fine.